# Running Libreoffice without a window manager - is there a way to specify window geometry?

Tags: linux, xorg, libreoffice

I'm experimenting with setting up LibreOffice in a 'kiosk' environment, running in a bare X session without a desktop environment or window manager.

LibreOffice does provide its own rudimentary window switching interface (via the Window menu) for switching between open documents, so users will be able to open multiple documents and switch between them.

The problem I'm having is getting LibreOffice to start full-screen. Without a window manager, there's no way to maximise or manipulate window positions once they appear, so to be useable, each LibreOffice window will have to start with window dimensions equal to the screen size.

Are there any undocumented command line arguments available to allow this, and if not, are there any easy workarounds?

Comment: Running a window manager would be an easy workaround, wouldn't it? They perform exactly this function: manage windows (decide their sizes and positions).